# Is that true that we can't create a browse button in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hello guys I am stuck at a point and i want ur help.First of all i want to clear that i am not a sharepoint developer but my boss gave me a task which i have to complete in 2 days . I want you ppl to help me to accomplish this task.I have two questions in my mind

1) Is that true that we can't create a browse button in sharepoint?

2) If there is a way to create browse button in sharepoint then pls explain here.And if not then what should i do to get browse button in sharepoint.

**EDIT:-**

I want a browse button like in picture,onclick which opens file uplod dialog.

Here's the picture.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "browse" button? Please ask your question more precise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not true. You can put any html in your web parts, master pages, or page layouts:

```
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
```

There is also an ASP.NET file upload button available, like so:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="FileUpload1" />
```

The "official" SharePoint way to do it would probably be having a document library in your site and doing this with javascript:

```
NewItem2(event, "/path/to/list/NewForm.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={fdcbd17c-9b66-449e-8875-d25de53f98d1}&RootFolder=");javascript:return false;
```

and if you have a web part (or any C#) generating this javascript, you should use the document library's DefaultNewFormUrl